# Эфект при наведение мышкой css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

при наведение на ссылку она меняет свой цвет во так

```
#bar > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Но если убрать мышку она снова меняет цвет на прежний. Как сделать так чтобы после наведения на элемент новый цвет текста сохранялся если мы убираем мышку с элемента, и менялся на предидущий, только если мы навели мышку на другой такой же элемент,(соответственно у второго цвет меняется на новый у первого на старый). Как в меню . ????

Comment: ну думаю тут тока js  поможет и обработка события

Comment: @Dmitriy вложенные меню делаете?

Answer (score 2):

Без JS тут никак, вот пример функции для одного пункта

```js
var element = document.getElementById("link");
element.onmouseover = function() {
 this.setAttribute("style", "color:red;");
}
```

```css
#bar > li > a {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="bar" style="">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="link">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```